# Why will enabling "pause on caught exceptions" improve my debugging experience?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Couldn't find anywhere why I should actually do this:

[image: Couldn't find anywhere why I should actually do this]

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: if you do pause on exceptions, you can see the stack at the time of the exception. You can see the call stack of functions that lead to the exception, as well as the current scope's variables, as they were at the time of the exception.

If you don't do this, JS will just fail this call stack, produce an exception in the console, and continue running the next statement. This will lead to the loss of the stack information at the time of the exception.

Comment: The question is tagged with `reactjs` which is very often used in combination with WebPack which in turn usually involves Babel. In other words, many, if not the overwhelming majority of React projects use Babel. Babel routinely throws and handles errors for its own internal operations (which I don't like but it doesn't change facts). For example, loading bootstrap can lead to dozens of caught errors even before anything interesting happens. Therefore, using `Pause On Caught Exceptions` is not feasible - at least on the actual projects i joined over time.